# Optimising the playing of two videos playing in two canvases clipped

Tags: canvas, optimization

I have a pair of videos that are playing inside canvases with clipping going on. Occasionally I just see black for the videos, unclipped and unrendered and the page has to be refreshed. Has anybody got any clue why this might be?

It has appeared to be working but I can also hear the video card slowly getting louder at times. Would it help to slow down the `requestAnimationFrame` function somehow, do you think? This whole thing has been very experimental and I could do with an extra pair of eyes.

Here is my source code and thank you in advance.

```js
function makeLeftCanvasPath(ctx, width, height, widthFifteenPercent) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
  ctx.lineTo(width, 0);
  ctx.lineTo(width - widthFifteenPercent, height);
  ctx.lineTo(0, height);
  ctx.lineTo(0, 0);
  ctx.closePath();
}

function makeRightCanvasPath(ctx, width, height, widthFifteenPercent) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(widthFifteenPercent, 0);
  ctx.lineTo(width, 0);
  ctx.lineTo(width, height);
  ctx.lineTo(0, height);
  ctx.lineTo(widthFifteenPercent, 0);
  ctx.closePath();
}

var VideoSplit = function(container, sourceA, sourceB) {
  var leftMediaSource = sourceA;
  var leftMuted = true;

  var leftCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  leftCanvas.id = 'leftCanvas';

  var ctxLeft = leftCanvas.getContext("2d");
  var leftVideoContainer;
  var leftVideo = document.createElement("video");

  leftVideo.src = leftMediaSource;
  leftVideo.autoplay = false;
  leftVideo.loop = true;
  leftVideo.muted = leftMuted;

  leftVideoContainer = {
    leftVideo: leftVideo,
    ready: false,
    ctx: ctxLeft
  };

  leftVideo.oncanplay = readyToPlayVideoLeft;

  var rightMediaSource = sourceB;
  var rightMuted = true;

  var rightCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');

  rightCanvas.id = 'rightCanvas';

  var ctxRight = rightCanvas.getContext("2d");
  var rightVideoContainer;
  var rightVideo = document.createElement("video");

  rightVideo.src = rightMediaSource;
  rightVideo.autoplay = false;
  rightVideo.loop = true;
  rightVideo.muted = rightMuted;

  $(rightVideo).attr('playsinline', '');

  rightVideoContainer = {
    leftVideo: rightVideo,
    ready: false,
    ctx: ctxRight
  };



  rightVideo.oncanplay = readyToPlayVideoRight;


  // Create an overlay to capture mouse events
  var eventOverlay = document.createElement('div');
  eventOverlay.classList.add('eventOverlay');


  container.appendChild(leftCanvas);
  container.appendChild(rightCanvas);
  container.appendChild(eventOverlay);


  // Syncronise dimensions:
  leftCanvas.width = leftCanvas.clientWidth;
  rightCanvas.width = rightCanvas.clientWidth;

  leftCanvas.height = leftCanvas.clientHeight;
  rightCanvas.height = rightCanvas.clientHeight;

  syncroniseCoordinateSystems();
  ctxLeft.save();
  ctxRight.save();




  function syncroniseCoordinateSystems() {
    // Syncronise dimensions:
    var containerWidth = window.getComputedStyle(container).width;


    container.style.height = (parseInt(containerWidth) / 100 * 56.25) / 2 + 'px';
    var height = parseInt(container.style.height);

    // Get 54.5% of the container width

    var percentageOfWidth = parseInt(containerWidth) / 100 * 54.5;

    leftCanvas.width = percentageOfWidth;
    rightCanvas.width = percentageOfWidth;

    leftCanvas.height = height;
    rightCanvas.height = height;

    leftCanvas.style.height = leftCanvas.height + 'px';
    rightCanvas.style.height = rightCanvas.height + 'px';


    var fifteenPercentOfWidth = rightCanvas.width / 100 * 15;
    makeLeftCanvasPath(ctxLeft, leftCanvas.width, leftCanvas.height, fifteenPercentOfWidth);
    ctxLeft.clip();

    makeRightCanvasPath(ctxRight, ctxRight.canvas.width, ctxRight.canvas.height, fifteenPercentOfWidth);
    ctxRight.clip();


  }

  function readyToPlayVideoRight(event) {
    rightVideoContainer.ready = true;
  }

  function readyToPlayVideoLeft(event) {
    leftVideoContainer.ready = true;
    requestAnimationFrame(updateCanvasLeft);
  }

  function updateCanvasLeft() {

    var containerWidth = window.getComputedStyle(container).width;

    // Set the style of the actual container so it retains video aspect ratio
    container.style.height = (parseFloat(containerWidth) / 100 * 56.25) / 2 + 'px';

    var height = parseFloat(container.style.height);
    var width = parseInt(containerWidth) / 100 * 54.5;


    // only draw if loaded and ready
    if (leftVideoContainer !== undefined && leftVideoContainer.ready && rightVideoContainer !== undefined && rightVideoContainer.ready) {
      ctxLeft.drawImage(leftVideoContainer.leftVideo, 0, 0, width, height);
      ctxRight.drawImage(rightVideoContainer.leftVideo, 0, 0, width, height);
    }

    requestAnimationFrame(updateCanvasLeft);
  }




  window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
    syncroniseCoordinateSystems();

    var fifteenPercentOfWidth = leftCanvas.width / 100 * 15;

    makeLeftCanvasPath(ctxLeft, leftCanvas.width, leftCanvas.height, fifteenPercentOfWidth);
    ctxLeft.clip();
    makeRightCanvasPath(ctxRight, ctxRight.canvas.width, ctxRight.canvas.height, fifteenPercentOfWidth);
    ctxRight.clip();
  });




  function playPauseClick(canvasClicked) {
    var canvasClickedId = canvasClicked.id;
    var videoContainer = (canvasClickedId == 'leftCanvas' ? leftVideoContainer : rightVideoContainer);

    if (videoContainer !== undefined && videoContainer.ready) {
      if (videoContainer.leftVideo.paused) {
        videoContainer.leftVideo.play();
      }
    }
  }

  eventOverlay.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
    var rect = this.getBoundingClientRect();
    var x = e.clientX - rect.left;
    var y = e.clientY - rect.top;

    if (ctxLeft.isPointInPath(x, y)) {
      leftVideo.play();
      rightVideo.pause();
    } else {
      leftVideo.pause();
      rightVideo.play();
    }
  });

  eventOverlay.addEventListener('mouseout', function(e) {
    leftVideo.pause();
    rightVideo.pause();
  });

};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could draw everything on a single canvas, with a single Path and no `clip()`.

By using several [compositing operations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalCompositeOperation), you can achieve the same result as your clipping:

- first fill your path in normal mode `source-over`.
- then draw your first video in `source-in` mode, so that only the pixels which will overlap the ones already there (i.e on your path) will stay.
- finally draw your second video in `destination-over` mode, which will draw it **behind** the existing pixels.

```js
VideoSplit(
  document.getElementById('container'),
  'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/transcoded/2/22/Volcano_Lava_Sample.webm/Volcano_Lava_Sample.webm.360p.webm',
  'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a4/BBH_gravitational_lensing_of_gw150914.webm'
);

function VideoSplit(container, sourceA, sourceB) {
  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  var video1 = loadVid(sourceA);
  var video2 = loadVid(sourceB);

  var width, height, long_width, short_width;

  var shouldResize = false,
    paused = false,
    canvas_rect = null;

  var loaded = 0;

  window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
    if(paused && !shouldResize) requestAnimationFrame(draw);
    shouldResize = true;
  });
  canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', toggleVid);
  canvas.addEventListener('mouseout', pauseVids);


  function init() {
    container.appendChild(canvas);
    resize();
    draw();
    pauseVids();
  }

  function resize() {
    var cont_rect = container.getBoundingClientRect();
    width = canvas.width = cont_rect.width;
    height = canvas.height = (cont_rect.width / 2) * 0.5625; // 16/9 ratio
    container.style.height = height + 'px';

    // since we are dealing with a single path, we can draw it only when resizing the canvas
    drawPath();
    // save our canvas bounding rect so we don't have to request it anymore
    canvas_rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    shouldResize = false;
  }

  function drawPath() {
    var w = width / 2,
      margin = w * (0.15 / 2);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineTo(0, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(w + margin, 0); // 7.5% on the right of the center
    ctx.lineTo(w - margin, canvas.height); // 7.5 % on the left of the center
    ctx.lineTo(0, canvas.height);
  }

  function draw() {
    if (shouldResize) {
      // resize only in the rAF callback, so it fires once per frame at max
      resize();
    } else {
      if (paused) return; // force redraw on resize, even if paused
      // micro-optimization... resizing already clears the canvas
      ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
    }
    var w = width / 2,
      margin = w * (0.15 / 2);

    ctx.fill(); // draws our Path
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-in'; // next drawing will occur only on the drawn Path
    ctx.drawImage(video1, 0, 0, w + margin, height);
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-over'; // next drawing will occur behind current drawing
    ctx.drawImage(video2, w - margin, 0, w + margin, height);

    requestAnimationFrame(draw); // do it again
  }

  function toggleVid(evt) {
    var mouse_x = evt.clientX - canvas_rect.left;
    var mouse_y = evt.clientY - canvas_rect.top;
    if (ctx.isPointInPath(mouse_x, mouse_y)) {
      video1.play();
      video2.pause();
    } else {
      video2.play();
      video1.pause();
    }
    if (paused) {
      paused = false;
      draw();
    }
  }

  function pauseVids() {
    video1.pause();
    video2.pause();
    paused = true;
  }

  function onVidload() {
    if (++loaded === 2)
      init();
  }

  function loadVid(url) {
    var video = document.createElement('video');
    video.src = url;
    video.onloadedmetadata = onVidload;
    video.onerror = function() {
      console.error('failed to load video resource, check you are on a browser that does support webm video format')
    };
    video.muted = true;
    video.repeat = true;
    video.play();
    return video;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
<p>mouse over the canvas to toggle the video's playing</p>
```

Comment: You're a genius! Thank you so much for this it's great!